# mysql not reverse sorting datetime field correctly

Tags: mysql, datetime, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a datetime field in descending order. It is sorting by day just fine. However, the time part is random. It sorts in ascending order perfectly.
Sample query:
`SELECT * FROM pcvisit WHERE page_id='0005e1ca1784383bf6bf032f33dc6e27' ORDER BY dtime DESC`
Result:

```
4adbc6b1cab4f14e7c9f2e308eb0944e | 0005e1ca1784383bf6bf032f33dc6e27 | 2011-02-23 16:08:35 | 1
733ab6507fbdab0e71f357f2f0ff6067 | 0005e1ca1784383bf6bf032f33dc6e27 | 2011-02-23 07:24:12 | 1
a5f9c9810e9648d2dbe4dec0e785216c | 0005e1ca1784383bf6bf032f33dc6e27 | 2011-02-23 05:26:59 | 1
981e24b4dd257f44a7a41dbdfe4def54 | 0005e1ca1784383bf6bf032f33dc6e27 | 2011-02-22 09:07:12 | 3
67906b350d59e97d7f56b7ceb254857e | 0005e1ca1784383bf6bf032f33dc6e27 | 2011-02-22 06:55:44 | 1
```

I have also tried:
`SELECT * FROM pcvisit WHERE page_id='0005e1ca1784383bf6bf032f33dc6e27' ORDER BY dtime DESC, TIME(dtime) DESC`
Trying my best to not have to split it into 2 fields.

Comment: It looks like the time is sorted in descending order correctly. Notice that the day is 22, when the time jumps back up to 09:07

Comment: Ack! I feel like an idiot for not looking closer. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date and time are being sorted correctly. Look closer. When the day changes to the 22nd, the time starts back at the top again, and starts descending. Its descending the date first, then by the time.

Answer (score 3):

The order in your second select is *primarily* on `dtime` and the time only affects it when the primary field is equal. In other words,

```
order by col1, col2
```

will effectively only use `col2` to order those rows that have identical `col1` values.

That's the way multi-column ordering works.

If you wanted something like *ascending* time within descending date, that would be a bit trickier but you'd just have to break out the date as well as time, something like:

```
order by date(dtime) desc, time(dtime) asc
```

And in that case, I really *would* consider breaking it into two separate columns for efficiency. You don't want to be doing per-row functions in your `order by` clauses - better to have separate indexes for them.

However, I don't think that's the case here. Since `dtime` is a date/time column, you're *already* sorting on both date and time so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve beyond that. Just use `order by dtime desc` as in your first example and it sorts correctly.